# Why my model function doesn't work in ZEND?

Tags: zend-framework, model, controller

I'm wondering what is wrong with my code : 
this is my function from my controller :

```
public function testareAction(){ 
    // $this->getResponse()->setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);
    //$myarray =  $_POST['data_post'];
    //$product_ids = $_POST['product_ids'];
    //$type = 1;
    $model = new Application_Model_Order(); 
    echo $model -> saveOrderNames();
}
```

and this my function from my model :

```
public function saveOrderNames(){
    return 1;
}
```

Why im not getting the result "1" in the browser? 
Im a newbie so please give me good speficitions.

thx :D
this is the index from the controller :

```
public function indexAction()
    {
        if (!($locationUrl = $this->_getParam('locationUrl'))) {
            throw new \Zend_Controller_Action_Exception('Location URL was not provided.', 404);
        }        

        $this->maiDivClass = "block clear step1";

        // get Location row
        $mapper = new DbTable\Location();
        $sql = $mapper->select()->where('url = ?', $locationUrl);

        if (!($this->view->location = $mapper->fetchRowActive($sql))) {
            throw new \Zend_Controller_Action_Exception('Location not found', 404);
        }

        // set active markup for location menu
        $this->_helper->layout()->locationMainMenuUrl = $this->view->location->url;

        // SEO
        $this->setSeo(
            $this->view->location->meta_title, 
            $this->view->location->meta_description, 
            $this->view->location->meta_keywords
        );

        // get day from param
        $dayName = $this->_getParam('day', Cronos::getCurrentDayName());

        $this->view->dayNo = Cronos::getWeekDayNumber($dayName);
        if ($this->view->dayNo === false) {
            throw new \Zend_Controller_Action_Exception('Invalid weekday provided.', 404);
        }

        $this->view->selectedDate = Cronos::getDateWithOffset($this->view->dayNo); // get date offset
        $this->view->categMapper  = new DbTable\Categories();

        $appCfg = new Zend_Config_Ini(APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini', APPLICATION_ENV);
        $this->view->s3 = "http://".$appCfg->custom->s3->bucket;
        $imgMapper = new Application_Model_Mapper_Images();
        $this->view->imgs = $imgMapper->fetchAllByLocationId($this->view->location->id);


        /**
         * Show products only for allowed admin emails. Testing only.
         * Admin must be logged in to see products, while the test is on.
         * 
         * To disable, change custom.test.isEnabled flag in app.ini.
         */
        $testCfg = Zend_Registry::get('Zend_Config')->custom->test->toArray();
        $isEnabled = (bool) $testCfg['isEnabled'];

        // test is enabled?
        if ($isEnabled) {
            $email = false; 
            $auth  = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
            // grab email, if logged in
            if ($auth->hasIdentity()) { $email = $auth->getIdentity()->email; }

            // has email? check it against config, else don't show products
            $showProducts = ($email) ? in_array($email, (array) $testCfg['email']) : false;

        // test is disabled: always show products
        } else {
            $showProducts = true;
        }

        if ($showProducts) {

            // get categories & products for this date and location
            $prodService = new \Application\Service\Products();
            $this->view->categsWithProds = $prodService->getProducts($this->view->location->id, $this->view->selectedDate); 

            //check days of the week with products
            $week = array();
            $currentDay = Cronos::getWeekDayNumberByDate();
            if($this->view->location->erp_name != "city lbox") {
                for($day=$currentDay;$day<7;$day++)
                {
                    $selectedDate = Cronos::getDateWithOffset($day);
                    $categswithprod = $prodService->getProducts($this->view->location->id, $selectedDate);
                    if(count($categswithprod))
                        $week[] = $day;

                }
                //we need to go to sunday and next week
                for($day=0;$day<$currentDay;$day++)
                {
                    $selectedDate = Cronos::getDateWithOffset($day);
                    $categswithprod = $prodService->getProducts($this->view->location->id, $selectedDate);
                    if(count($categswithprod))
                        $week[] = $day;
                } 
            } else {
                for($day = $currentDay; $day<7;$day++) {
                    $week[] = $day;
                }
                for($day = 0; $day<$currentDay; $day++) {
                    $week[] = $day;
                }
            }

            $this->view->week = $week;
            $specialMenuRows = $this->view->location->getSpecialMenus(new Zend_Date());
            $this->view->specialMenus = $this->view->partial('_partials/specialMenu.phtml', array('specialMenus' => $specialMenuRows));

            $this->view->categsWithProdsALaCarte =  $prodService->getProducts($this->view->location->id, $this->view->selectedDate, 1);

        // no xml; show "Download PDF"
        } else {
            $this->setPdfLink();
            $this->renderScript('location/no_xml.phtml');
        }
    }
```

OK , I created in the models folder this file : OrderNames.php
and this is what my model contains :

```
<?php
    class OrderNames {

        public function saveOrderNames(){
                 return 1;
                } 
    }   
?>
```

and this is the function from controller :

```
public function testareAction(){ 
        $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
        $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);
        echo "1tralala";
        $model = new Application_Model_OrderNames(); 
        echo "2<hr>";
        $model -> saveOrderNames();

}
```

why the string "2tralala" doesnt appear ?

Comment: Take an action that works, paste your code in, and make var_dump to debbug.
Maybe it's your call to action that is badly made, perhaps it is your model that is not placed in the correct directory. You should also add isset on your post variables

Comment: if I use var_dump($model -> saveOrderNames()) , it doesn't show anything.

Comment: the model "Order.php" is placed in the "models" directory

Comment: try var_dump($model); is empty? if yes try to replace `$model = new Application_Model_Order(); 
    echo $model -> saveOrderNames();` by `echo 'foo';`

Comment: it is also empty, everything that i display after "$model = new Application_Model_Order();"  is empty

Comment: Just for test, take an action that works (like Index controller and index action or other), paste your code in.

Comment: I updated my post. this is not my code I inherited it !

Comment: Just for test, remove code indexAction and put in the code testareAction, normally, you should have the good information, no?

Comment: I updated my post , please check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call: `$model = new Application_Model_OrderNames();`
the name of php file is `OrderNames.php`
and the class is

```
class OrderNames {

    public function saveOrderNames(){
             return 1;
            } 
}
```

so try to replace the name of the class:

```
class Application_Model_OrderNames {...
```

Comment: I replaced the class name with "OrderNamesTest" and the code from the testareAction into this : "$model = new Application_Model_OrderNamesTest();". and as you said the file name is still OrderNames.php. And i didn't get the echo "string", other options ?

Comment: No, if you want a `foo` model, you must have a `Foo.php` in `application/models`. In the `Foo.php`, the class must be `class Application_Model_Foo{...}` and the call to the foo class is `new Application_Model_Foo{();`